# .Htaccess rewrite all to friendly url except if folder, and name is ..?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I have a rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|etc|flv|swf|mp4|mov)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /detail.php?type=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

It rewrites `site.com/detail.php?type=2&url=3` to `site.com/type/url`

Now I have a folder, `site.com/admin/` and when I type in `site.com/admin/` it sends me to a rewritten page because of htaccess, how can I prevent the htaccess rewrite from working if folder name is admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another RewriteCond to exclude the admin folder

```
#exclude /admin/ folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|etc|flv|swf|mp4|mov)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /detail.php?type=$1&url=$2 [L]
```